# Can Google Firebase be considered a middleware?

Tags: firebase, middleware

I read that a middleware is a software/API/Cloud service that acts abstracting the usage of some functionality, for example, if I want a message to be sent from a client to a server, I could implement all the messaging API for myself or I could use a middleware where I could just create a client and a server and send a message following its protocol and the magic would be done behind the scenes.

With Firebase, this is kind of what happens, e.g. using Firebase database, I can tell it to store a certain string (from the client's part) and retrieve it (from the server's side), so to me it seems that Firebase acts as a middleware.

Is Google Firebase a middleware? If it is not, why?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-firebase-middleware-in-the-cloud-called-functions-beta-is-now-available-fe977f94c0b0

Answer (score 2):

Firebase isn't middleware.  It's better classified as a [platform as a service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service), or a [backend as a service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service).  There are lots of different products that make up the Firebase platform, and each one has its own way of providing services to mobile applications via SDKs.

Whether or not Firebase is classified as a "middleware" should be mostly irrelevant to developers.  You just use SDKs to access backend services, and monitor them in the Firebase console.  What goes on in the middle is an implementation detail.